# Render icon to the right side in the JList using DefaultListCellRenderer

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, renderer

I have a `DefaultListCellRenderer` in my program and it does all the work fine but I was wondering if I can add image to the far right in the `JList` instead  of putting it to the left.

Is it possible to render icon to the right side in the `JList` using `DefaultListCellRenderer`?

And if yes help me use that in following code.

```
public class RCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    String runm = "";

    public RCellRenderer(String runm) {
        this.runm = runm;

    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("images/in.png");
        setIcon(imageIcon);
        if (value.equals(runm)) {
            Color fg = Color.BLACK;
            setForeground(fg);
        }


        return c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't read the image in the renderer. That code will be invoked for all rows in the list. The image should be read once in the constructor.

Comment: That's just for now I have to add different images for different entries but not getting how to show them on right side

Comment: `can add image to the far right in the JList instead of putting it to the left.` - you need to clarify the requirement. It seems like you have text and icon to display. Do you want the text on the left edge of the column and the Icon at the right edge? Or do you want the text and icon at the right edge? Or are you just trying to display an Icon?

Comment: i have both text and icon to display but want the text to the left edge and the icon to the right edge.And if possible like to add two icons,one to the left edge and other to the right.

Comment: `I have to add different images for different entries` - then you should have a custom Object that is added to the ListModel containing the text and icon values. Then in your custom renderer you set the text and icon from the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want the text to the left edge and the icon to the right edge

The default renderer for a JList is a JLabel. A JLabel does not support a dynamic gap between the text and icon (only a fixed gap).

You have a couple of options:

1. You could try to make the gap dynamic. You set the text/icon of the label and get its preferred size. You also know the size of the JList to you can calculated the difference to be the gap between the text and icon. Then you invoke the `setIconTextGap(...)` method to set the gap. You would also need to set this gap to 0, before invoking the super.getCellRendererComponent(...) method. You would also need to use Andrew's suggestion to align the icon to the right of the text.
2. Use a custom renderer that uses a JPanel as the renderer. Then you would use a BorderLayout for the panel. You would add a "textLabel" to the BorderLayout.LINESTART and an "iconLabel" to the BorderLayout.LINE_END of the panel. Then in the rendereing code you simple set the text/icon of the two labels. You would also need to implement the highlight code for the selected row of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The default component used in a renderer is a `JLabel`, so call [`JLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.WHATEVER)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalTextPosition-int-).

Comment: thanks Andrew but i am not able to get how to use that in my code can you help me with that please.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).